# Rhombus Identification: 3 sides equal + 2 parallel sides?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

### Rhombus Identification: 3 sides equal + 2 parallel sides?

---

**Context:**

---

I'll keep this brief.

I had a question, and in it, I needed to prove something is a rhombus. Now, obviously we can do:

1. Parallelogram + Adjacent Sides Equal Proof.
2. Diagonals meet at right angles.
3. Diagonals bisect both pairs of opposite angles.

However, in this case, I proved 3 sides were equal (Including 2 parallel sides), and 2 sides were parallel. In all honesty, I could've gone further to prove the other two were parallel - but I didn't (consider this like a practice test where I'd rather not go back and change answers after checking :)

---

**The question:**

---

Is this enough? Does proving 3 sides are equal and 2 parallel proves the 4th is equal and thus prove it is a rhombus?

Comment: It depends which sides of the three given ones are equal. If these are the parallel sides the claim holds. If they are not parallel - the claim does not hold.

Comment: Yes, the parallel sides are equal. Can you elaborate on why that is so - that is, in an answer? I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Ok. I will have a look at your edit.

Comment: Ah - I see now.

Comment: Do you still need an answer or could answer the question yourself?

Comment: Will self answer thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay - so thanks to the help of @user, I now understand - I think.

Because I have shown that two parallel sides are also equal, the entire shape then becomes a parallelogram. Then, since the 3rd side is adjacent and is equal, it is a parallelogram with adjacent sides equal --> it is a rhombus.

Answer (score 0):

If you can prove three sides are equal and two of those are parallel, then yes. This is because a quadrilateral with two sides equal and parallel is a parallelogram, and you also know that two adjacent sides of this parallelogram are equal, so it must be a rhombus.

However, if there are three equal sides, one of which is parallel to the fourth side then you could have an isosceles trapezium (for example, the shape consisting of three equilateral triangles put together).